How to count generation of a parent-child hierarchical data in sas?
I have a dataset looks like this:
child $ parent $ 
A        .
B       A 
C       A
D       B
E       C
F       D
G       E

It means A is the ancestor who has generation = 1, B and C are children of A so generation = 2, etc.
How can I calculate generation for the dataset?
the output I expect looks like:
child $ parent $ generation
A          .       1
B       A        2
C       A        2
D       B        3
E       C        3
F       D        4
G       E        4


You can use a hash for navigating through parents to root in valid hierarchy.
Example:
Does not check for id:pid pairs that might be a cycle (and would cause infinite loop in sample code)
data have (keep=id pid label='Random generation hierarchy with 15% root nodes');
  call streaminit(2024) ;

  retain id pid . ;

  nid = 100 ;
  do id = 1 to nid ;
    if id = 1 or id/nid <= 0.15 then do ;
      output ;
    end ;
    else do ;
      pid = rand('integer',1,id-1);
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;

data want(keep=id pid gen root) ;
  retain id pid gen root . ;
  declare hash g(dataset: 'have') ;
  g.defineKey('id') ;
  g.defineData('id', 'pid') ;
  g.defineDone() ;

  declare hash h() ;
  h.defineKey('ix_id') ;
  h.defineData('gen', 'root') ;
  h.defineDone() ;

  declare hiter iter('g') ;

  do ix = 1 by 1 while (iter.next() = 0) ;
    ix_id = id ;

    * go up the parent ids until root ;
    do gen = 0 by 1 while (g.check(key:pid) = 0) ;
      g.find(key:pid) ;
    end ;

    root = id ;
    g.find(key: ix_id) ;
    output ;
  end ;

  stop ;
  format _numeric_ 6. ;
run ;

proc sort data=want ;
  by root gen pid ;
run ;


You just keep rejoining the output with the input.  To do that you will need to use macro logic so that you can repeatedly generate SAS code.
First let's convert your listing into an actual dataset.
data have;
  input child $ parent $ ;
cards;
A        .
B       A
C       A
D       B
E       C
F       D
G       E
;

Then let's define a macro.  First it should setup the target dataset by finding all of the top level nodes (the one's without parents).  Then it can loop adding the children into the next level until there are no children found.
%macro levels(in=,out=);
%local level nobs;

data &out;
  set &in nobs=nobs;
  if _n_=1 then call symputx('nobs',nobs);
  level=1;
  if missing(parent);
run;

proc sql;
%do level=1 %to &nobs ;
create table next as 
  select a.child,a.parent,&level+1 as level
  from &in a 
    inner join &out(where=(level=&level)) b
    on a.parent = b.child
;
  %let nobs=&sqlobs;
insert into &out select * from next;
options _last_=&out;
drop table next;
  %if &nobs < 1 %then %do;
quit;
    %return;
  %end;
%end;
quit;
%if &nobs>0 %then %put NOTE: Please check for cycles in your tree.;
%mend levels;

Then you can call the macro passing in your dataset.
%levels(in=have,out=want);

Result:
Obs    child    parent    level

 1       A                  1
 2       B        A         2
 3       C        A         2
 4       D        B         3
 5       E        C         3
 6       F        D         4
 7       G        E         4


Hi Tom, thank you for your answer it works well. Just want to clarify the purposes of two statements in the code: 1. options last=&out; 2.   %if &nobs < 1 %then %do; quit; %return;. In 2, what return do there?

The %RETURN will end the macro at that point.  The options statement will just set the automatic macro variable &SYSLAST to the output dataset.  It just makes it so if you add a proc print' or other step after the macro call without specifying which dataset to use it  will use the output dataset instead of the temporary next dataset.
